# Where to add safe.directory for Gitlab Docker Executor

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a pipeline on a Docker-Windows Executor on my own Container. When running the pipeline I get the error `detected dubious ownership in repository at ...`. The error message also suggests adding the directory as a safe directory `git config --global --add safe.directory <directory>`.

I have tried doing this on my Host, but it didn't fix the issue. I'm assuming this is because this applies the setting to the git configuration on the host, while the problem arises in the Container.
Where do I need to run the command to solve the issue?
And if I have to run it in the container, do I have to run it every time I run the pipeline? I'm assuming yes, because the container gets deleted after the run.

To add a bit of background information: On my development machine (Win11 Pro), I'm running a gitlab-runner with `docker-windows` setting as well as Docker desktop, which has the windows image I'd like to use. While the pipeline is running, I can see the helper spin up in Docker a couple of times, but the second one fails with Error(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as described above is that the safe.directory needs to be added 1) before pulling and 2) every time, because the container gets deleted after the run.

This can be done in the config.toml of the gitlab runner, by adding an entry in the `[[runners]]` section: `pre_clone_sript = "git config --global --add safe.directory <directory>"`